# Install an old version of Ubuntu, say, 11.04 over my current 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, installation, versions

is it possible to install another version of Ubuntu in my newest version 11.10? Something doesn't work well in this new version; see [my post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32776/pgf-doesnt-work-under-ubuntu-11-10). I may need to switch back. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Specifically, you want to downgrade, but keep all your settings and files?

Comment: Thanks root45. I have fixed the problem. See my post above. It might not be the problem of TeXlive 2009. It might be the problem of pgfmath.sty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about install "in" unless you use a virtual machine. You can install "over" by getting a 11.04 CD and installing like you did 11.10.
You don't happen to have a separate /home partition do you?

 Either way it seems like backing up your data and doing a fresh install is what you're looking for. 
 If you're fortunate enough to have a separate /home partition, when you install select the "manual" or "something else" (no really, that's what it's called in 11.10). Then Highlight the partition you want as root (/), set the mount point to **/**. Then select the partition you want to use for /home, and set it as **/home**.

 This will let you keep your personal data, while installing the new OS.

 If you don't have a separate /home partition do a standard install and consider making one with gparted.

Comment: Oops. Must have missed your comment while I was typing the above. Glad you got it straight.

Comment: Thanks Argusvision. Your answer is still valuable for us. Fortunately, 11.10 is not that inconvenient.:-)